# How can I create nodejs schemaless structure?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am developing nodejs backend, I want to create schema less structure of model.
I create it following way.

`questionnaireModel.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.schema;
var bcrypt  = require ('bcrypt-nodejs');
var QuestionnaireSchema = mongoose.Schema({},{strict:false});

module.exports = mongoose.model('questionnaire', QuestionnaireSchema);
```

is it right?

My controller is here:

`questionnaireController.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config');
var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment');
var questionnaire = mongoose.model("questionnaire");

exports.createQuestionnaire = function (req, res) {
var receivedValues = req.body;
    var questionnaireData = new questionnaire();
    questionnaireData.categoryid = req.body.categoryid;
    questionnaireData.questiontype = req.body.questiontype;
    questionnaireData.isrequired = req.body.isrequired;
    questionnaireData.isshowvalue = req.body.isshowvalue;
    questionnaireData.options = req.body.options;
    questionnaireData.createdDate = moment().format();
    questionnaireData.save(function(err,resp){
            res.json({
              "code": 200,
              "status": "success",
            });
    });
}
```

But the data is not inserted in collection.

I passed below data using Postman:

```
{
 "categoryid":"123",
 "questiontype":"checkbox",
 "isrequired":true,
 "isshowvalue":true,
 "options":{
    "op1":"123",
    "op2":"1234"
 }
}
```

Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want schema-less, don't use mongoose, because you're basically violating everything that mongoose is there for. Just use `mongodb` or other similar drivers.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts okay. then what should i use? what is alternate option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it works.

`questionnaireModel.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var QuestionnaireSchema = mongoose.Schema({ any: {}, },
{
  strict: false
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('questionnaire', QuestionnaireSchema, 'questionnaire');
```

`questionnaireController.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment');

var questionnaire = mongoose.model("questionnaire");

exports.createQuestionnaire = function (req, res) {
    var requestBody= {};
    requestBody = req.body;

    questionnaire.create(requestBody,function(err,res){
          console.log("data instert successfully")
    })
 }
```

i use create method.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and its working.

**Schema of questionnaire**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

// var bcrypt  = require ('bcrypt-nodejs');


var QuestionnaireSchema = new Schema({

}, { strict: false });

module.exports = mongoose.model('questionnaire', QuestionnaireSchema);
```

**Routes :**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('../config/Database');


mongoose.connect(config.mongo_local,function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("$$Database is not connected");
    }else{
        console.log("##Database is connected");
    }
});

// var async = require('async');
var moment = require('moment');
var questionnaire = require("../models/questionnaire");

router.post('/createQuestionnaire', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var obj= {};
    obj = req.body;

    new questionnaire(obj).save(function(err,resp){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Data is created");
            res.json({
              "code": 200,
              "status": "success",
            });
        }
    })

});
```

When you are doing {strict : false}, you need to pass values to model at constructor level or if you are creating object and then assigning values then you have to use *set()*

```
var questionnaireData = new questionnaire();
questionnaireData.set('categoryid', req.body.categoryid);
```

Hope it will help you.